# Debugging PostgreSQL triggers performance

Tags: postgresql, query-optimization, cascade

I have a slow delete query. I used `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` to understand the bottleneck and I saw two triggers that are slow:

```
Trigger for constraint other_table_1_fid_fkey: time=3.644 calls=1
Trigger for constraint other_table_2_fid_fkey: time=6.289 calls=1
```

Following [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/37034/very-slow-delete-in-postgresql-workaround#comment430283_138270) discussion I added indexes.
The index on `fid` in `other_table_1` indeed improved the performance.
But adding an index on `fid` in `other_table_2` didn't make any difference, and it is seems to be the bottleneck in the `delete` query.

My question is how can I debug (or `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`) the trigger itself.

Thanks,

P.S
To solve my concrete problem I temporary remove the foreign key constraint and it improved the performance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set these parameters:

```
shared_preload_libraries = 'auto_explain'
auto_explain.log_min_duration = 0
auto_explain.log_analyze = on
auto_explain.log_buffers = on
auto_explain.log_triggers = on
auto_explain.log_nested_statements = on
```

Then restart PostgreSQL (so that `shared_preload_libraries` takes effect) and execute the statement again. You will find the execution plans of all SQL statements in the trigger functions in the PostgreSQL log. That will enable you to find and tune slow statements.